# "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, android

I keep getting this error, but I can't find out what is causing it.

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"
```

Here is the JavaScript I am trying to run. It is in Android Studio and Java:

```
"javascript: var y = document.querySelector('#login-form [type="+"'"+"submit"+"'"+"]'); y.click();"
```

Comment: Check your quotes: `document.querySelector('#login-form [type='submit']');`

Comment: take a look at the source in your browser when you run this javascript. What is the js that's shown? + try to use double-quotes for the type=submit. In Java escape the " sign (\").

Comment: @Andreas `document.querySelector('#login-form [type="submit"]')` surely.

Comment: @Andy That would be the solution. I've just posted the unobfusticated version so the problem get's more obvious.

Comment: So why the `javascript:`? What is that being used for?

Comment: I am trying to make a button click through a webview in Android Studio @epascarello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
"javascript: var y = document.querySelector('#login-form [type=\"submit\"]');
    y.click();"
```

Comment: Why the extra `"'"` makes no sense

Comment: " " - it's external quotes, used to divide the string. ' - it's inside quotes to keep logic inside that string.

Comment: Thankt alot it helped!

Comment: Edited. This should make sense now.

Comment: @OkkeTrommelen glad to help:)